# Tic Tac Toe Java Program - CPU not responding

Tags: java, cpu

I've been working on this program for a couple weeks now, adding components to an applet in order to output a simple tic tac toe game. I've gotten some of it to work, but as of now, when you run, all it does is that you click it once, the CPU projects its mark in the upper left corner, and then you can click anywhere else and it automatically says you win. I can't get the CPU to keep playing. I don't expect anyone to tell me what to do, but I'm just confused as to which method I need to work on in order to get the CPU to respond. My professor has left some very helpful pseudocode, but I still don't quite understand. I've been working with the method "gameEnd," checking for winners horizontally, vertically and diagonally to see if that's the source to getting the game to continue beyond just two marks, but it's not working. Anyone got any suggestions? Thanks.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Event;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Random;

public class TicTacToe extends java.applet.Applet {

    // Ignore this constant
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1942709821640345256L;

    // You can change this boolean constant to control debugging log output
    private static final boolean DEBUGGING = false;

    // Constants

    // Size of one side of the board in pixels
    private static final int BOARD_SIZE_PIXELS = 600;
    // Number of squares on one side of the board
    private static final int SQUARES = 3;
    // Diameter of the circle drawn in each square
    private static final int CIRCLE_WIDTH = 90;

    // Colors to be used in the game
    private static final Color BACKGROUND_COLOR = Color.WHITE;
    private static final Color SQUARE_BORDER_COLOR = Color.BLACK;
    private static final Color GAME_OVER_MESSAGE_COLOR = Color.BLACK;
    private static final Color HUMAN_COLOR = Color.RED;
    private static final Color HUMAN_WINNING_COLOR = Color.MAGENTA;
    private static final Color CPU_COLOR = Color.BLUE;
    private static final Color CPU_WINNING_COLOR = Color.CYAN;

    // Status constant values for the game board
    private static final int EMPTY = 0;
    private static final int HUMAN = 1;
    private static final int HUMAN_WINNING = 2;
    private static final int CPU = -1;
    private static final int CPU_WINNING = -2;

    // String displayed when the game ends
    private static final String GAME_WIN_MESSAGE = "You win! Click to play again.";
    private static final String GAME_LOSE_MESSAGE = "You lose......Click to play again.";
    private static final String GAME_DRAW_MESSAGE = "No one wins? Click to play again...";

    // Instance variables that control the game

    // Whether or not the user just clicked the mouse
    private boolean mouseClicked = false;
    // Whether or not to start the game again
    private boolean restart = false;
    // Whether or not the CPU should start playing a move.
    // USED ONLY WHEN THE CPU PLAYS FIRST!
    private boolean onFirstMove = false;
    // The column and row of the SQUARE the user clicked on
    private int xMouseSquare; // column
    private int yMouseSquare; // row
    // The width (and height) of a single game square
    private int squareWidth = BOARD_SIZE_PIXELS / SQUARES;
    // An array to hold square status values on the board.
    // The status values can be EMPTY, HUMAN, CPU or other values
    private int[][] gameBoard;
    // The column and row of the SQUARE the CPU player will move on
    private int xCPUMove;
    private int yCPUMove;

    // Add the rest of your instance variables here, if you need any. (You won't
    // need to, but you may if you want to.)

    // Ignore these instance variables

    // CPUinMove represents if the CPU is thinking (generating the CPU move).
    // If it is true, it means the CPUMove() method is running and no new move
    // should be added
    private boolean CPUinMove;



    // Methods that you need to write:

    /*
     * Pre: x and y are x-coordinate and y-coordinate where the user just
     * clicks. squareWidth is the width (and height) of a single game square.
     * 
     * Post: xMouseSquare and yMouseSquare are set to be the column and row
     * where the user just clicked on (depending on x and y).
     * 
     * Hint: You need only two statements in this method.
     */
    // Setting MouseSquare equal to x and y divided by the Square Width to create a location for
    // the user after clicking
    private void setMouseSquare(int x, int y) {
        // 
        xMouseSquare = x/squareWidth;
        yMouseSquare = y/squareWidth;
    }

    /*
     * Pre: SQUARES is an int that holds the number of game squares along one
     * side of the game board. xSquare is an int such that 0 <= xSquare <
     * SQUARES. CIRCLE_WIDTH is an int that holds the diameter of the circle to
     * be drawn in the center of a square. squareWidth is an int that holds the
     * width and height in pixels of a single game square.
     * 
     * Post: Return the correct x-coordinate (in pixels) of the left side of the
     * circle centered in a square in the column xSquare.
     * 
     * Hint: This method should be very simple. What you need to do is to find
     * the right equation.
     */
    private int getIconDisplayXLocation(int xSquare) {

        // This line is an example of using DEBUGGING variable
        if (DEBUGGING) {
            System.out.println("The input that getIconDisplayXLocation() receives is: " + xSquare);
        }

        // equation that returns the correct variable in the column xSquare
        return squareWidth * xSquare + (squareWidth - CIRCLE_WIDTH)/2;
    }

    /*
     * Pre: SQUARES is an int that holds the number of game squares along one
     * side of the game board. ySquare is an int such that 0 <= ySquare <
     * SQUARES. CIRCLE_WIDTH is an int that holds the diameter of the circle to
     * be drawn in the center of a square. squareWidth is an int that holds the
     * width and height in pixels of a single game square.
     * 
     * Post: Return the correct y-coordinate (in pixels) of the top of the
     * circle centered in a square in the row ySquare.
     * 
     * Hint: This method should be very simple. What you need to do is to find
     * the right equation.
     */
    private int getIconDisplayYLocation(int ySquare) {
        // This line is an example of using DEBUGGING variable
        if (DEBUGGING) {
            System.out.println("The input that getIconDisplayYLocation() receives is: " + ySquare);
        }

        // equation that returns the correct variable in the column ySquare
        return squareWidth * ySquare + (squareWidth - CIRCLE_WIDTH)/2;
    }



    /*
     * The instance variable gameBoard will be created and initialized
     * 
     * Pre: SQUARES is set to an int. gameBoard is a 2-dimensional array type
     * variable that holds the status of current game board. Each value in the
     * array represents a square on the board
     * 
     * Post: gameBoard must be assigned a new 2-dimensional array. Every square
     * of gameBoard should be initialized to EMPTY.
     * 
     * Hint: A loop.
     */
    private void buildBoard() {
        // Setting the two methods equal to local variables, x and y
        int x = xMouseSquare;
        int y = yMouseSquare;
        // This line creates the gameBoard array. You must write several more
        // lines to initialize all its values to EMPTY
        // Write game board using the equation of three across and down for each column

        // Constructs a 3 by 3 array of integers for the board
        gameBoard = new int[3][3];
        // Initialize variables i and j, set equal to 0; this establishes a connection for loop
        for (x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            for (y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
                gameBoard[x][y] = EMPTY;
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * Returns whether the most recently clicked square is a legal choice in the
     * game.
     * 
     * Pre: gameBoard is a 2-dimensional array type variable that holds the
     * status of current game board. xSquare and ySquare represent the column
     * and row of the most recently clicked square.
     * 
     * Post: Returns true if and only if the square is a legal choice. If the
     * square is empty on current game board, it is legal and the method shall
     * return true; if it is taken by either human or CPU or it is not a square
     * on current board, it is illegal and the method shall return false.
     * 
     * Hint: Should be simple but think carefully to cover all cases.
     */
    private boolean legalSquare(int xSquare, int ySquare) {
        if (gameBoard[xSquare][ySquare] == EMPTY)
        return true;
     else return false; 
    }

    /*
     * Pre: gameBoard is an array that holds the current status of the game
     * board. xSquare and ySquare represent the column and row of the most
     * recently clicked square. player represent the current player (HUMAN or
     * CPU). This method is always called after checking legalSquare().
     * 
     * Post: Set the square as taken by current player on the game board if the
     * square is empty.
     * 
     * Hint: Very simple.
     */
    private void setMovePosition(int xSquare, int ySquare, int player) {
        player = HUMAN;
        player = CPU;
        this.xMouseSquare = xSquare;
        this.yMouseSquare = ySquare;
    }

    /*
     * Check if HUMAN or CPU wins the game.
     * 
     * Pre: gameBoard is an array to hold square status values on the board. The
     * status values can be EMPTY, HUMAN, CPU or other values.
     * 
     * Post: The method will return true if and only if a player wins the game.
     * Winning a game means there is at least one row, one column, or one
     * diagonal that is taken by the same player. The method does not need to
     * indicate who wins because if it is implemented correctly, the winner must
     * be the one who just made a move.
     * 
     * Hint: Complicated method. Use loops to shorten your code. Think about how
     * to represent "a player takes 3 squares in a row/column/diagonal".
     */

    private boolean gameEnd() {
        // Setting local variables
        int i = 0;
        int x = xMouseSquare;
        int y = yMouseSquare;
        int sw = squareWidth;
        int[][] g = gameBoard;
        // Checking for a winner

        // Checking columns
        for (y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
        for (x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            i = g[x][y] + i;

        }
    }       
        {   

        // Checking rows
        for (x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
        for (y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
            i = g[x][y] + i;
            }
        }   
    }       

        // Checking first diagonal

        {

        for (x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            g[x][x] = 3;

            }
        }

        for (x = 1; x < 3; x++) {
            g[x][x] = 3;

        }

        for (x = 2; x < 3; x++) {
            g[x][x] = 3;

        }

        // Checking second diagonal
        for (y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
            g[y][2 - y] = 3;    

        }

        for (y = 1; y < 3; y++) {
            g[y][2 - y] = 3;

        }

        for (y = 2; y < 3; y++) {
            g[y][2 - y] = 3;

        }

        return true;
    }

    /*
     * Check if the game ends as a draw.
     * 
     * Pre: gameBoard is an array to hold square status values on the board. The
     * status values can be EMPTY, HUMAN, CPU or other values. This method is
     * always called after gameEnd().
     * 
     * Post: The method will return true if and only if all squares on the game
     * board are taken by HUMAN or CPU players (no EMPTY squares left).
     * 
     * Hint: Should be simple. Use loops.
     */
    // Value of...

    private boolean gameDraw() {
        if (squareWidth == (3^2 - 1)) {
        }
    return true;
        }

    /*
     * Marks circles on the line on which a player wins.
     * 
     * Pre: g is Graphics object that is ready to draw on. HUMAN_WINNING_COLOR
     * and CPU_WINNING_COLOR are both Color objects that represent the color to
     * show when HUMAN/CPU wins. gameBoard is gameBoard is an array to hold
     * square status values on the board. The status values can be EMPTY, HUMAN,
     * CPU or other values.
     * 
     * Post: ALL the row(s)/column(s)/diagonal(s) on which a player wins will be
     * marked as the special color.
     * 
     * Hint: You must draw a new circle with the special color (to replace the
     * old circle) on the square if the square belongs to a winning
     * row/column/diagonal. You can change gameBoard because the board will be
     * reset after displaying the winning line. You can use helper methods
     * (existing ones or your own) to finish this method. Pay attention that
     * many functions in this method is similar to gameEnd(). You should think
     * about reusing code.
     * 
     * Hint2: This method is not necessary for the game logic. You don't have to
     * start it early. Start when you know everything else is correct.
     */

    private void markWinningLine(Graphics g) {
        // TODO
    }

    /*
     * Generates the next square where the CPU plays a move.
     * 
     * Pre: gameBoard is an array to hold square status values on
     * the board. The status values can be EMPTY, HUMAN, CPU or other values.
     * 
     * Post: Set xCPUMove and yCPUMove to represent the column and the row which
     * CPU plans to play a move on. The respective square MUST BE EMPTY! It will
     * cause a logical error if this method returns a square that is already
     * taken!
     * 
     * Hint: Don't start too early -- currently this method works (though
     * naively). Make sure that everything else works before touching this
     * method!
     */

    private void CPUMove() {
        // TODO
        // The following block gives a naive solution -- it finds the first
        // empty square and play a move on it. You can use this method to test
        // other methods in the beginning. However, you must replace this block
        // with your own algorithms eventually.



        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if (gameBoard[i][j] == 0) {
                    xCPUMove = i;
                    yCPUMove = j;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    /* Put any helper methods you wish to add here. */

    /* You will not need to change anything below this line. */

    /*
     * DO NOT change this method.
     * 
     * Set the game board to show a new, blank game.
     */
    private void wipeBoard(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(BACKGROUND_COLOR);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, BOARD_SIZE_PIXELS, BOARD_SIZE_PIXELS);
    }

    /*
     * DO NOT change this method.
     * 
     * Displays a circle on g, of the given color, in the center of the given
     * square.
     */
    private void displayHit(Graphics g, Color color, int xSquare, int ySquare) {
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillOval(getIconDisplayXLocation(xSquare),
                getIconDisplayYLocation(ySquare), CIRCLE_WIDTH, CIRCLE_WIDTH);
    }

    /*
     * DO NOT change this method.
     * 
     * This method handles mouse clicks. You will not need to call it.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean mouseDown(Event e, int xMouse, int yMouse) {
        if (isClickable()) {
            mouseClicked = true;
            setMouseSquare(xMouse, yMouse);
        }
        repaint();
        return true;
    }

    /*
     * DO NOT change this method.
     * 
     * This method handles drawing the board. You will not need to call it.
     */
    @Override
    public void update(Graphics g) {
        paint(g);
    }

    /*
     * DO NOT change this method.
     * 
     * Draws the border between game squares onto canvas. Also, draws the moves
     * that are already made.
     */
    private void displayGame(Graphics canvas) {
        canvas.setColor(SQUARE_BORDER_COLOR);
        for (int i = 0; i < BOARD_SIZE_PIXELS; i += squareWidth) {
            for (int j = 0; j < BOARD_SIZE_PIXELS; j += squareWidth) {
                canvas.drawRect(i, j, squareWidth, squareWidth);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < SQUARES; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < SQUARES; j++) {
                switch (gameBoard[i][j]) {
                case HUMAN:
                case HUMAN_WINNING:
                    displayHit(canvas, HUMAN_COLOR, i, j);
                    break;
                case CPU:
                case CPU_WINNING:
                    displayHit(canvas, CPU_COLOR, i, j);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * DO NOT change this method.
     * 
     * This method relays information about the availability of mouse clicking
     * in the game. You will not need to call it.
     */
    private boolean isClickable() {
        return !CPUinMove;
    }

    /*
     * DO NOT change the contents this method.
     * 
     * If this method is changed to public void paint(Graphics canvas), it will
     * execute the program with the CPU-first order.
     * 
     * This method is like the "main" method (but for applets). You will not
     * need to call it. It contains most of the game logic.
     */
    // @Override
    public void paint(Graphics canvas) {
        displayGame(canvas);
        if (mouseClicked) {
            if (onFirstMove) {
                CPUMove();
                setMovePosition(xCPUMove, yCPUMove, CPU);
                displayHit(canvas, CPU_COLOR, xCPUMove, yCPUMove);
                onFirstMove = false;
            } else {
                if (restart) {
                    wipeBoard(canvas);
                    setUpGame();
                    repaint();
                } else if (legalSquare(xMouseSquare, yMouseSquare)) {
                    setMovePosition(xMouseSquare, yMouseSquare, HUMAN);
                    displayHit(canvas, HUMAN_COLOR, xMouseSquare, yMouseSquare);
                    if (gameEnd()) {
                        markWinningLine(canvas);
                        canvas.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 30));
                        canvas.setColor(GAME_OVER_MESSAGE_COLOR);
                        canvas.drawString(GAME_WIN_MESSAGE, squareWidth / 2,
                                squareWidth);
                        restart = true;
                    } else {
                        CPUinMove = true;
                        CPUMove();
                        setMovePosition(xCPUMove, yCPUMove, CPU);
                        displayHit(canvas, CPU_COLOR, xCPUMove, yCPUMove);
                        CPUinMove = false;
                        if (gameEnd()) {
                            markWinningLine(canvas);
                            canvas
                                    .setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN,
                                            30));
                            canvas.setColor(GAME_OVER_MESSAGE_COLOR);
                            canvas.drawString(GAME_LOSE_MESSAGE,
                                    squareWidth / 2, squareWidth);
                            restart = true;
                        } else if (gameDraw()) {
                            canvas
                                    .setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN,
                                            30));
                            canvas.setColor(GAME_OVER_MESSAGE_COLOR);
                            canvas.drawString(GAME_DRAW_MESSAGE,
                                    squareWidth / 2, squareWidth);
                            restart = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            mouseClicked = false;
        }
    }

    /*
     * DO NOT change this method.
     * 
     * This method is like the "main" method (but for applets). You will not
     * need to call it. It contains most of the game logic.
     */
    public void paint_game(Graphics canvas) {
        // display the current game board
        displayGame(canvas);

        // the following block will run every time the user clicks the mouse
        if (mouseClicked) { // when the user clicks the mouse
            // if the game is ready to start or to be restarted
            if (restart) {
                // clear the window and set up the game again
                wipeBoard(canvas);
                setUpGame();
                repaint();
            }
            // else, if the game is in play, check if the click is on a legal
            // square
            else if (legalSquare(xMouseSquare, yMouseSquare)) {
                // if the square is legal, mark the corresponding position as
                // taken by HUMAN
                setMovePosition(xMouseSquare, yMouseSquare, HUMAN);
                // display the new position with a HUMAN_COLOR circle
                displayHit(canvas, HUMAN_COLOR, xMouseSquare, yMouseSquare);
                // check if the game ends (if it is, HUMAN wins)
                if (gameEnd()) {
                    // if HUMAN wins, mark the winning line as a special color.
                    markWinningLine(canvas);
                    // display the human winning message
                    canvas.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 30));
                    canvas.setColor(GAME_OVER_MESSAGE_COLOR);
                    canvas.drawString(GAME_WIN_MESSAGE, squareWidth / 2,
                            squareWidth);
                    // mark the game as ready to restart
                    restart = true;
                } else if (gameDraw()) {
                    // if HUMAN doesn't win but the board is full, it is a draw
                    // display the draw message
                    canvas.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 30));
                    canvas.setColor(GAME_OVER_MESSAGE_COLOR);
                    canvas.drawString(GAME_DRAW_MESSAGE, squareWidth / 2,
                            squareWidth);
                    // mark the game as ready to restart
                    restart = true;
                } else {
                    // if HUMAN doesn't win and the board is not full, the CPU
                    // is ready to move
                    CPUinMove = true;
                    // calculates the next CPU move
                    CPUMove();
                    // mark the corresponding position as taken by CPU
                    setMovePosition(xCPUMove, yCPUMove, CPU);
                    // display the new position with a CPU_COLOR circle
                    displayHit(canvas, CPU_COLOR, xCPUMove, yCPUMove);
                    CPUinMove = false;
                    if (gameEnd()) {
                        // if CPU wins, mark the winning line as a special
                        // color.
                        markWinningLine(canvas);
                        // display the human losing message
                        canvas.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 30));
                        canvas.setColor(GAME_OVER_MESSAGE_COLOR);
                        canvas.drawString(GAME_LOSE_MESSAGE, squareWidth / 2,
                                squareWidth);
                        // mark the game as ready to restart
                        restart = true;
                    }
                    // else (if the game is not ended after the CPU move), the
                    // game is ready to get the next HUMAN move
                }
            }
            mouseClicked = false;
        }
    }

    /*
     * DO NOT change this method.
     * 
     * This method initializes the applet. You will not need to call it.
     */
    @Override
    public void init() {
        setSize(BOARD_SIZE_PIXELS, BOARD_SIZE_PIXELS);
        setBackground(BACKGROUND_COLOR);
        setUpGame();
    }

    /*
     * DO NOT change this method.
     * 
     * Creates a fresh game board and sets up the game state to get ready for a
     * new game.
     */
    private void setUpGame() {
        buildBoard();
        CPUinMove = false;
        restart = false;
        onFirstMove = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: look at setMovePosition I think this function cause the problem.. because the player is always set to be the CPU

Comment: add a boolean to check if it's the pc turn or the user turn..
you can initialize it to true (means user turn) and when the user ends his move set the boolean to false (means pc turn), when the pc end his move, set it back to true.. and on setMovePosition check the boolean value and then you'll which player had a move

Comment: `setMovePosition` sets the passed in parameter `player` (twice). This variable goes out of scope at the end of the function (as parameters do), thus assigning it a value without using it is pointless. Did you mean to set a class variable instead?

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the replies everyone! @Dukeling I'm honestly not sure. I don't think so, I was just trying to trigger what the my professor has already set up in place that would target the integer "player" (he said in the pseudocode it's set to both Human and CPU). Elior, am I able to establish a boolean value under setMovePosition though?

Comment: Well, I didn't read all your code, so I'm not sure of the intention, but I know Java well enough to know that neither `player = HUMAN;` nor `player = CPU;` does anything useful in the context of that function for the reason stated above. Just letting you know.

Comment: Ohh, gotcha. Okay, yeah, I didn't think I did that right. That's all I wanted to know, cause based on what I've read of what he himself wrote, I'm 99 percent sure it's this small little section that's causing me grief. Thanks for taking a look! Greatly appreciated